How the timing of death can be linked to wrongdoing of doctor?
We know in Islam, Allah has timed everything, from born, to how much will you earn and how ane when you die. When a doctor mistreat a patient or gave them a wrong medicine, they die or get so ill that there health won't be the same anyone. Is that written in his qadr? or someone who commit suicide e.g someone who is doing well financially and then something happens in life and they commit suicide, all of these sudden instance or mistake causes person to die, so does mean it was there time and Allah has writthen for them to die in such a way?
Today while in hospital, I was given something that made my blood pressure drop so much that I was almost fainted and bright light was so much that I was looking in sun, but later I got ok, so that question is in my head as my mother in law died by hands of doctor too few years back, while I say it was qadr but my wife say it was mistake of doctor and she would have been alive if doctor took her seriously

Qadr and the means of death are not mutually exclusive. If someone dies due to a mistake of a doctor then it was destined that she would die due to that reason.

Mistakes, even those that are due to negligence and even if they cause death are not sins. The doctor would not be sinful for the death until and unless he was proved to have intentionally caused it.
